# CSS to SVG Loader Image

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to replicate this excellent [Loader](http://codepen.io/merelyjeremy/pen/yEDlF) in SVG. Here is how far I have [gotten](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yEqwd). The difficulty that I am running into is that SVG seems to be designed to work in rectangular (x,y) type coordinates. I wonder if there is a way to use radial coordinates (r, theta)? If anyone can set me in the right direction, that would be much appreciated. Is using SVG the way to go here?

Desired loader screenshot:

[image]

My current progress screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You can do this with CSS responsively as well, especially using a pre-processor like SASS or LESS. You could position them using a rotating then translating it, then set transform-origin and scale in addition to changing opacity

Comment: The original author used SASS. I figured it might be more efficient to use SVG though. I figured it was unnecessary to add a bunch of DOM elements. One <img> element can take care of it all now.

Comment: Just noting that it's possible (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be exactly what you want, but it might provide a starting point and may help you get your loader working.

Using JavaScript you can build the SVG and avoid the repetition:

```
<div id="container">
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
   <defs>
      <rect id="r" x="50" y="-10" height="20" width="75" rx="10"/>
      <g id="g">
        <animateTransform
            attributeName="transform" begin="0s" dur="1s"
            type="rotate" 
            values="330;300;270;240;210;180;150;120;90;60;30"
            repeatCount="indefinite" 
            calcMode="discrete"
        />
        <use xlink:href="#r" opacity="1"/>
        <use xlink:href="#r" opacity=".9"  transform="rotate(30)  scale(0.95)" />
        <use xlink:href="#r" opacity=".8"  transform="rotate(60)  scale(0.9)"  />
        <use xlink:href="#r" opacity=".7"  transform="rotate(90)  scale(0.85)" />
        <use xlink:href="#r" opacity=".6"  transform="rotate(120) scale(0.8)"  />
        <use xlink:href="#r" opacity=".5"  transform="rotate(150) scale(0.75)" />
        <use xlink:href="#r" opacity=".4"  transform="rotate(180) scale(0.7) " />
        <use xlink:href="#r" opacity=".3"  transform="rotate(210) scale(0.65)" />
        <use xlink:href="#r" opacity=".2"  transform="rotate(240) scale(0.6) " />
        <use xlink:href="#r" opacity=".15" transform="rotate(270) scale(0.55)" />
        <use xlink:href="#r" opacity=".1"  transform="rotate(300) scale(0.5)"  />
        <use xlink:href="#r" opacity=".05" transform="rotate(330) scale(0.45)" />
      </g>
    </defs>
    <use id="loader" xlink:href="#g" transform="translate(150,150)"></use>
</svg>
```

See it working here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/SQW8j/)

**Update**: Here's another [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/NTxeA/) using the same component. This one also animates the colors while spinning.

Comment: Might include the function you used to create it :)

Comment: This is pretty cool. Thanks for the input. How did you get that though? It sounds like you used JS with a template to draw this out?

Comment: @ZachSaucier I actually typed it in by hand :)

Comment: @helderdarocha All the better! I assumed you did from the way you phrased your answer

Comment: @ZachSaucier Yes. I was actually suggesting JavaScript to not type everything as I did.

Comment: It does not work correctly in Firefox (latest version, 30 as of the time of this writing). Do you know why?

Comment: @DiodeDan Yes. The first `<use>` tag was not closed. It seems that Chrome tolerates not-well-formed SVG when embedded in HTML. I fixed it. It should work now.

Comment: @helderdarocha Neato! Thanks, this is really cool. Can you explain why you use y=-10 in the <rect>?

Comment: @DiodeDan That's to align the rectangle with the center of the `x` axis. Since the rectangle has a width of 20, -10 will place it in the middle. The `x="50 is to move the rectangle away from the center of rotation"`